# How does context work on Android?

Tags: android

I know it will sound dumb or people will just say: read the documentations available. But i can't get to understand how Context works. Yes, android.content.Context

Can someone help me??

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API states (with important information bolded):

> **android.content.Context:**
>
> Interface to **global information** about
>   an application **environment**. This is an
>   abstract class whose implementation is
>   provided by the Android system. It
>   allows **access** to **application-specific
>   resources and classes**, as well as
>   **up-calls** for application-level
>   operations such as launching
>   activities, broadcasting and receiving
>   intents, etc.

It's in the [`android.content`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/package-descr.html) package, which implements the concept of [content providers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html). Content providers abstract out data access from data stores in a REST-like way.

But **more specifically**, *what* don't you understand? You need to make your question more specific or else there's not much we can help you with.